# What is the difference between the two different codes of Bahdanau's Attention given in Official Tensorflow tutorials?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, attention-model

I was reading and coding for Machine Translation Task and stumped across the two different tutorials.

One of them is [Caption Generation using Visual Attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning) paper implementation where they have used Image features of `[64,2048]` in a way such that each image is a sentence of 64 words and each word in the sentence having an embedding of 2048 length. I totally get that implementation and here is the code below for `Bahdanau's Additive style Attention`:

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

  def call(self, features, hidden):
    hidden_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(hidden, 1)
    attention_hidden_layer = (tf.nn.tanh(self.W1(features) + self.W2(hidden_with_time_axis)))
  
    score = self.V(attention_hidden_layer)

    attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

    context_vector = attention_weights * features
    context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)
    
    return context_vector, attention_weights
```

But when I went to [Neural Machine Language Translation Task](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/nmt_with_attention), I found this complex there which I am not able to comprehend what is happening here:

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super().__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, use_bias=False)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, use_bias=False)
    
    self.attention = tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention()

  def call(self, query, value, mask):
    w1_query = self.W1(query)
    w2_key = self.W2(value)

    query_mask = tf.ones(tf.shape(query)[:-1], dtype=bool)
    value_mask = mask

    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(inputs = [w1_query, value, w2_key],mask=[query_mask, value_mask],return_attention_scores = True,)
    return context_vector, attention_weights
```

I want to ask

1. **What is the difference between the two?**
2. **Why can't we use the Code for Caption Generation in the Second one or vice versa?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output shapes of Keras AdditiveAttention Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353657/output-shapes-of-keras-additiveattention-layer)

Comment: So you mean to say we can use both things in both tasks interchangeably, if I can pass my in and out parameters of same shape?

Comment: They look like two different implementations of the same thing, with subtle differences between them. Looking at the code, I don't think they would have any practical difference in performance. However, to get the correct exact implementation, you'll have to go through the paper that introduced Bahdanau Attention.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Are they producing the `decoder_state_t` from using the scores, current  word and `hidden_decoder state_t-1`. And then again using that word, scores and this `new_decoder_state_t` to produce vectors? I think they are doing this on the second code. Can you comment?